# How do I write a ternary operator for this line?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I can't figure out how to write a ternary operator for the ending of this line (i.e. "location" and "description"). I've defined the `$location` and `$description` variables but I'm getting an error that says `unexpected $location variable`.

Basically, for both location and description, I'm trying to say: If the field has been filled out, display the field. If not, don't print anything.

```
$content .= '<div data-order="' . $count . '" data-group="' . $group . '"><div class="img-wrap"><img data-iwidth="'.$isize[0].'" data-iheight="' . $isize[1] . '" class="myslide" data-lazy="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/slides/' . strtolower($group) . '/' . $image_url . '" alt="' . get_sub_field('title') . '"><div class="slide-caption"><strong>' . get_sub_field('title') . '</strong><hr>' . get_sub_field('location') ? '<em>'$location'</em>' : ''; . get_sub_field('description') ? '<hr><span class="details">Details [+]</span><div class="details-display">'$description'</div>' : ''; . '</div></div></div>';
```

Here is the full context:

```
if( have_rows('slides', $frontpage_id) ):
    while ( have_rows('slides', $frontpage_id) ) :
        the_row();
        $group = get_sub_field('group');
        $count = 1;
        $i = 0;

        $nav .= '<ul id="nav_'.$group.'" style="display: none;">';
        $content .= '<div class="image-data-container image-container-'. $group .'">';
        while( have_rows('images') ) : the_row(); $count++;
            $image_url = get_sub_field('image');
            $location = get_sub_field('location');
            $description = get_sub_field('description');
            $isize = @getimagesize(get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/slides/' . strtolower($group) . '/' . $image_url);
            $content .= '<div data-order="' . $count . '" data-group="' . $group . '"><div class="img-wrap"><img data-iwidth="'.$isize[0].'" data-iheight="' . $isize[1] . '" class="myslide" data-lazy="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/slides/' . strtolower($group) . '/' . $image_url . '" alt="' . get_sub_field('title') . '"><div class="slide-caption"><strong>' . get_sub_field('title') . '</strong><hr>' . get_sub_field('location') ? '<em>'$location'</em>' : ''; . get_sub_field('description') ? '<hr><span class="details">Details [+]</span><div class="details-display">'$description'</div>' : ''; . '</div></div></div>';
            $nav .= '<li ><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="change_gallery" rel="' . $i . '" data-group="' . $group . '">' . get_sub_field('title') . '</a></li>';
            $i++;
        endwhile;
        $content .= '</div>';
        $nav .= '</ul>';

    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: That's already pretty unreadable as it is. You *don't* want to add a ternary condition on top. (And fix the string concatenation syntax issues first.)

Comment: The line is long enough as it is. I'd suggest splitting it across multiple lines using a regular if statement where necessary. Part of the issue you're having is where you forget to concatenate your strings and variables. E.g. `'<em>'$location'</em>'` should be `'<em>' . $location . '</em>'`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. I'm still learning. I'm not sure how to make it better formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Other the fact that your $content variable is a formatting nightmare. The ternary operator syntax returns result based on the condition and it should be separated from your $content attribute

```
$someVariable = (get_sub_field('location')) ? '<em>'.$location.'</em>' : '';
```

Now use that some variable inside your `$content` variable instead

**Here is your code with comments:**

```
while( have_rows('images') ) : the_row(); $count++;
  $image_url = get_sub_field('image');

  // you have already defined the location variable here 
  // It also means and I am assuming they your get_sub_field is returning a string
  // If you are receiving a boolean or null value than and than only than you can do your ternary condition call of
  // get_sub_field('location') ? '<em>'$location'</em>' : ''
  // and if you are receiving a string field then you will have to explicitly check the condition
  // something like this (get_sub_field('location') === '') ? '<em>'$location'</em>' : ''
  // I am not that familiar with wordpress framework or the ACF plugin but it looks like get_sub_field will return something so you actually wont need the ternary condition
  $location = get_sub_field('location');
  // Similar case with description
  $description = get_sub_field('description');
  $isize = @getimagesize(get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/slides/' . strtolower($group) . '/' . $image_url);
  // After removing the ternary condition your content variable will look like this
  $content .= '<div data-order="' . $count . '" data-group="' . $group . '"><div class="img-wrap"><img data-iwidth="'.$isize[0].'" data-iheight="' . $isize[1] . '" class="myslide" data-lazy="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/slides/' . strtolower($group) . '/' . $image_url . '" alt="' . get_sub_field('title') . '"><div class="slide-caption"><strong>' . get_sub_field('title') . '</strong><hr>' . '<em>' . $location . '</em>' . '<hr><span class="details">Details [+]</span><div class="details-display">' . $description . '</div>' . '</div></div></div>';
  $nav .= '<li ><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="change_gallery" rel="' . $i . '" data-group="' . $group . '">' . get_sub_field('title') . '</a></li>';
  $i++;
endwhile;
```

You know you can always make it more readable

```
// You know instead of all the concatenation you can do this instead
  $templateDirURI = get_template_directory_uri();
  $groupLower = strtolower($group);
  $title = get_sub_field('title');
  $content .= "<div data-order='{$count}' data-group='{$group}'><div class='img-wrap'><img data-iwidth='{$isize[0]}' data-iheight='{$isize[1]}' class='myslide' data-lazy='{$templateDirURI}/img/slides/{$groupLower}/{$image_url}' alt='{$title}'><div class='slide-caption'><strong>{$title}</strong><hr><em>{$location}</em><hr><span class='details'>Details [+]</span><div class='details-display'>{$description}</div></div></div></div>";
```

**Updated Code**

```
  $content .= "<div data-order='{$count}' data-group='{$group}'><div class='img-wrap'><img data-iwidth='{$isize[0]}' data-iheight='{$isize[1]}' class='myslide' data-lazy='{$templateDirURI}/img/slides/{$groupLower}/{$image_url}' alt='{$title}'><div class='slide-caption'><strong>{$title}</strong>";
  // Assuming the user did not submit location information
  if($location !== "")
    $content .= "<hr><em>{$location}</em><hr>";
  if($description !== "")  
    $content .= "<span class='details'>Details [+]</span><div class='details-display'>{$description}</div>";
  $content .= "</div></div></div>";
```

Comment: Are you saying that I should edit the `location` and `description` variables directly? Like this? `$locationFetch = (get_sub_field('location')) ? '<em>'.$location.'</em>' : '';` How can I use `$location` if it hasn't been defined? Sorry, I'm a total newbie so please don't assume much.

Comment: @J82 see my comments now

Comment: That's how I had it before. But if the user does not fill out a field (for example, `location` or `description`), certain HTML shouldn't display. That's why I thought I had to use a ternary operator. For example, if the user doesn't fill out the `description` field, this should not display: `<span class='details'>Details [+]</span><div class='details-display'></div>`

Comment: That's easy.. you concatenate only those tags which satisfies the value in the variable.